# Nested IF statements in PHTML

Tags: html, magento, php

Evening,

I tried to edit a simple code in Magento, yet im totaly new to PHTML and im having problems with basics...

I wanted to check the title to set a custom div for the translator to invoke...

This part of the edited PHTML code does not work...

```
<?php if( $this->getConfig('title') ): ?>
  <?php if( $this->getConfig('title') == 'Categories' ?>
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Categories') ?></strong></div>
  <?php else: ?>
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?php echo $this->getConfig('title') ?></strong></div>
  <?php endif ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

While this original code works:

```
<?php if( $this->getConfig('title') ): ?>
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?php echo $this->getConfig('title') ?></strong></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can some expert please pinpoint an error so I wont spend whole bunch of time on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the second line. A your shorthand if statement doesn't have the closing parenthesis and colon like `...'Categories'): ?>`. Also your second to last `endif` doesn't have a semicolon after it.

Comment: OMG, what a bunch of newb typoes... i tried the semicolon after endif but that made no difference. It was the missing ): ! Please copy my code nad fix the typos so I can accept your answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php if( $this->getConfig('title') ): ?>
  <?php if( $this->getConfig('title') == 'Categories'): ?>
                                                  ---^
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Categories') ?></strong></div>
  <?php else: ?>
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?php echo $this->getConfig('title') ?></strong></div>
  <?php endif; ?>
          ---^
<?php endif; ?>
```