# How to Wrap A Condition Inside Another Condition in PHP

Tags: php

Can anyone please help me wrap the condition inside another condition in php.

I have this code #1 that I want to be inside code #2.

Here's code #1

```
<?php if( get_field('highlights') ): ?>
    <div class="overview">
    <h3>Quick Overview</h3>
    <?php the_field('highlights'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here's code #2

```
<?php if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'www.example.com')) 
{
  echo '**CODE #1 should be placed here**';
}
?>
```

Sorry, I don't haev any knowledge in PHP.

Wrapping code 1 inside code 2

Answer (score 0):

After several trial and error, here's what I have to make it work. Please correct me if there's something wrong or to improve.

```
<?php if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'www.google.com')){ ?>
      
    <?php if( get_field('highlights') ):?>
      <div class="overview">
      <h3>Quick Overview</h3>
      <?php the_field('highlights'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: There is a similar question, did you try the solution from it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911605

Answer (score 0):

This should work in theory. Though I'm unsure what the `highlights` field is for.

```
<?php 
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'www.example.com')){
  if( get_field('highlights') ){ ?>
    <div class="overview">
    <h3>Quick Overview</h3>
    <?php the_field('highlights'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php 
  }
}
?>
```

You may want to replace `<?php the_field('highlights'); ?>` with something like `<?=highlight ?>` and iterate through the highlights in a loop. That depends on the situation though.